# CentOS7 PHP 5.6 missing from ius-community repo

Tags: centos, php, centos7, php56

In the past I have installed the ius-community repo and then installed php56u like so:

```
yum install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
yum install php56u
```

Now that I have come to do the same on a new system, the php56u package seems to be missing. I read they renamed it to mod_php but that is also not found (for 5.6). Only the php7.2 package is available.

```
yum list php56u
Error: No matching Packages to list
yum list mod_php56u
Error: No matching Packages to list
yum list mod_php72u
Available Packages
mod_php72u.x86_64            7.2.15-1.ius.centos7
```

Looking at the [repo here](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/x86_64/repoview/) it is also not showing on that list. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get them.

[IUS removes packages](https://ius.io/LifeCycle/) from its repositories when those packages are no longer supported by their developers. [PHP 5.6 went end of life](https://secure.php.net/eol.php) at the end of last year, thus IUS removed the PHP 5.6 packages.

Your developers need to update their code to work with PHP 7, and have completed that work last year. That hard deadline has passed, now it must be done *today*.

Comment: As I agree upgrading is the best course of action, it's not always available. A workaround here if you cannot upgrade is to use the archive repo flag. The following works on centos 7 with the new repo URLs which took an age to work out:

 rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
    && rpm -Uvh https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm \
    && yum update -y \
    && yum --enablerepo ius-archive -y install php72u